# How to handle Russian links?

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, cyrillic

My boss today told me she needs a Russian translation on the website. 
Current URL structure looks like this:

```
www.website.com/en/product/product_name
```

where "en" will be changed to ru;

"product_name" should show, you know, product name...

There is admin panel where she can input everything herself.
Do I need to change Cyrillic Russian letters? Can it be done with PHP?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to translate to russian? How to store russian characters? How to rewrite the URLs? How to transmit the data from the admin panel to a DB?

Comment: Well, you somehow need to map the cyrillic product names to latin ones. Easiest is to do that on php level, either using a separate catalog (probably in a database, unless the number of products is trivial) or by adding those alternate product names to the product table (if the number of languages will stay really small).

Comment: I'm asking should I convert Russian letters or can I use them?
Is www.website.com/ru/product/производ valid link? Because of "производ " part. And if I need to, how to do that. Do I just add a separate field in database and display that? I know how to store and everything, just currently there isn't anything to handle Cyrillic in admin part cirrently

Comment: Certainly cyrillic characters can be part of a valid URL, sure. This is the time of IDN URLs...

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently, you can use Cyrillic alphabet without any problems, so no need for any PHP modifications. 
Thanks to arkascha